# I want to show the subcategories in alphabetical order in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is the code that I am using:

//here main categories are shown

```
      $w=mysql_query("select * from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id='$xresult[term_id]' "); //

      while( $wresult=mysql_fetch_array($w)) 

      {

     // at here i want that the list will be shown in alphabetic order


      $po=mysql_query("select * from wp_posts where ID='$wresult[object_id]' and post_status='publish' "); 

      $pod=mysql_fetch_array($po);

      $qq=mysql_query("select * from wp_postmeta where post_id='$pod[ID]' and meta_key='phone'");

      $q=mysql_fetch_array($qq);


          ?>
<li>

<a class="col-xs-6" href="<?php echo home_url();?>/store/<?php echo $pod['post_name']; ?>/"><p><?php echo $pod['post_title']; ?></p></a>

<span class="col-xs-6"><?php echo $q['meta_value'];?></span>
```

Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question or problem? Don't be lazy...

Comment: use ORDER BY in mysql query: select * from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id='$xresult[term_id]' ORDER BY name